# Boost 1.65.1 serialization to vector fails with 'Assertion initialized_ failed'

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I have the following test case that serializes  an int into `std:vector`.

It crashes with the following assertion:

```
serialization_test: /usr/include/boost/iostreams/detail/optional.hpp:55: T& boost::iostreams::detail::optional<T>::operator*() [with T = boost::iostreams::detail::concept_adapter<boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::vector<char> > >]: Assertion `initialized_' failed.
```

Any ideas? I think this should work...

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(serialize_base_test)
{
    int t = 42;
    std::vector<char> buffer;

    iostreams::back_insert_device<std::vector<char>> sink{buffer};
    iostreams::stream<iostreams::back_insert_device<std::vector<char>>> os;
    os.open(sink);
    archive::binary_oarchive oa(os);

    oa << t;
    os.flush();
    os.close();

}
```

**edit:** I simplified the test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructor for an archive should be called before the stream is closed because it restores any altered stream facets to their state before the archive was opened.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. The `binary_oarchive` does something inside its destructor that requires that the stream is still open. 
The following works:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(serialize_base_test)
{
    int t = 42;
    std::vector<char> buffer;

    iostreams::back_insert_device<std::vector<char>> sink{buffer};
    iostreams::stream<iostreams::back_insert_device<std::vector<char>>> os;
    os.open(sink);
    {
        archive::binary_oarchive oa(os);
        oa << t; 
    }

}
```

Comment: The flush and close are redundant now